# R Shiny: session object not found

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a UI that includes a navbarpage and 3 tabPanels.
The first tabPanel has widgets for selecting files.
once the users finishes selecting the files, there is a update button
which is watched  by observeEvent. Wehn the button is pressed, urls are
accessed and a table is filled. I want the panel to automatically switch.
So I used updateNavbarPage as seen in the code below.

This throws and error that   "session" can not be found. After throwing
this error  by whole enviroment is trashed and even if I remove the
call to updateNavPage  the code refuses to run unless i shut down
and start over

```
library(shiny)





shinyServer(function(input, output,sesson) {

  MY_DATA <- NULL



  fetch_files <- reactive({
    spatial   <- input$spatial
    location  <-input$location
    time      <-input$time
    metric    <-input$metric
    stat      <- input$stat
    provider  <- input$provider
    processing <- input$processing

    X <- FILES %>% filter(Spatial %in% spatial & Locale %in% location & Time 
                                  %in% time & Processing %in% processing & 
                                   Metric %in% metric &
                                  Stat %in% stat & Provider %in% provider)
    return(X)

  })

  display_files <- reactive({
    D <- fetch_files() %>% select(-DOI,-AccessDate,-Url,-DataID)
    return(D)

  })

  observeEvent(input$fetchData,{
    updateNavbarPage(session,inputId="main",selected="transform")
    MY_DATA <<- download_data(fetch_files())

  })

  output$active_data <-renderDataTable(MY_DATA)


  output$data_to_fetch <-renderDataTable( 
    display_files()
   )

})
```

Answer (score 2):

I just assume by first look on Your code that You made a typo:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,sesson){...
```

You should write `session` instead of `sesson`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){...
```

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed That. There must be something else wrong with the code as well. Starting from scatch.